# How to talk about your family/parents without saying if it's your Mother or Father specifically? Any legal issues for writing about your parent(s)?

Tags: defamation, family

*Reformulated in other's words (thank you commenters, mods please preserve the comments as originally posted so you can read the source), my question is:*

- **(A) Is referring to a parent specifically defamation?**
- **(B) Is defaming an ambiguously defined parent still defamation?**
- **(C) Would it be a problem to talk about your parents?**
- **(D) Why would that be defamation to talk about your parents?**
- **(E) Do lawyers use ambiguous terms such as "a family member" mostly when the detail is irrelevant or they don't know enough about the matter they assess or litigate? Will they look ridiculous if they limit themselves to "family member" in legal cases?**

*In my own words, as originally asked with my anecdote (which led to the great reformulations), same meaning as (A) to (E) before:*

I'm an American who at a French youth-in-difficulty shelter in Montreal was invited to talk to and ask the in-shelter Free Legal Aid Clinic with English law students from McGill University my title question, after I had asked before to a counselor the title question.

Specifically of course defamation (or libel, slander, etc, may be especially valid if they will still be living too) are legitimate legal issues (besides social/psychological issues) in not wanting to express the words Mom/Dad/Mother/Father (and not to mention their name[s]) at will, though I've been told the "truth" of the matter gives creedance/freedom if to fair use of the words (yet proof of family issues can vary, I could not exactly ask a publisher to clear and vet, **basically speaking about 'family with fact' when encountering emotional/psychological/verbal issues is daunting/troubling** [the words Mom/Dad remain important as much as sounding implicatingly litigatable {even the hint/whiff of knowing who/which parent can be drastic}, and **e.g. verbal abuse is not readily valued verbatim for "truth"/fact**]), I still know and worry the words are triggering and have long suffered to speak and talk about family given the variables said.

I feel (from personal experience) there is a legal grey area where speaking about parent(s) specifically is judged somewhat and would appreciate clarification if there is any legal precedent (for other written works, the general signal I read is to avoid real names mostly, how normally you may be required to fictionalize characters, but I find that difficult if the names are Mom/Dad—is that normal and because of the law?), and if my being younger or older mattered (being 17 or 18 matters if naming parents?) for using the words "Mother" and "Father" openly, say with my own public social media network writing for example if I mention family and or family issues.

Given the nature of how I was referred by my counselor/intervenor/social worker to Legal Aid for the title of my question (almost the exact words I asked originally), I figured appropriate to ask here for a second opinion. Relevant US/CA/international law or precedent/examples would be good to start first with.

*It may help to remind readers the title question is written clearly, even if the **anecdote of my real, detailed experience is clearly difficult for some people to relate**, so to repeat:*

- **(F) How do you talk about your family/parents without saying if it's your Mother or Father specifically? Any legal issues for writing about your parent(s)?**
- **(G) Are there any legal issues for writing about your parent(s)?**

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on the exact question.  Are you asking if referring to a parent specifically can be defamation?  Are you asking if defaming an ambiguously defined parent would be defamation?

Comment: @R I understand, it's not always clear talking about the law and family issues, even in the best of circumstances there can be communication issues describing how Family an the Law intersect in reality.  I think you understood very well the first time you read me, in fact. That can be normal in conversation to repeat what someone else says to help understand them. Specifically, in regards to your asking `"Are you asking if referring to a parent specifically can be defamation?"` = CORRECT &&  `"Are you asking if defaming an ambiguously defined parent would be defamation?"` CORRECT respectively.

Comment: I must say I have no idea what you are trying to ask. Why would it be a problem to talk about your parents? Why would that be defamation?

Comment: @gnasher7 You have the idea, you just do not feel comfortable stating with confidence what I said in your own words apparently, even though you did very well reading me. Given you had the ability to parse me well enough to form your questions, I will address as follows (1) `"Why would it be a problem to talk about your parents?"`: Good question! I rarely use exclamation points, ever. Really good question. (2) `"Why would that be defamation?"`Excellent question!!! I ask myself why I am warned, talked to, moderated, policed, and psychologized by others for talking ABOUT my PARENT(S) AS-IF a LAW.

Answer (score 3):

> Any legal issues for writing about your parent(s)?

No. Furthermore, the [answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/56985/how-to-talk-about-your-family-parents-without-saying-if-its-your-mother-or-fath/56986#56986) you got from the Free Legal Aid Clinic is wrong. There is no need for pseudonyms or ambiguities such as "*a family member*". As long as your *statements of fact* are truthful, identifying actual individuals in your narrative is lawful (this applies to US as well as Canada defamation law).

A word of caution, though: Your post reflects deficiencies in how you explain yourself. This has more to do with your way of articulating ideas than the possibility that English might not be your first language. Although it is palpable from your post that you do not intend to defame someone, reading it raises some concern that you might inadvertently convey a defamatory falsehood when you talk about matters which are understandably sensitive. Knowing how to transmit your message clearly and accurately is far more important --and safer from a legal standpoint-- than avoiding ironic acronyms such as "*A m o m f*".

Comment: Curious if specific (types of) lawyers (or legal situations) use particular phrases/wording for "a family member" like that, why do you think the free student lawyer suggested that as an idea, was it a competent response, or were they just humoring me, could there be any viable reason for altering my English to use their idea? I was rather proud to have the line I learned, & figured it came from some source of meaning, to defend me. Ideally nobody would care about hints (given the lack of clear English about if the Mom/Dad is the factual cause, can be literacy er just age, theoretically).

Comment: "*why do you think the free student lawyer suggested that as an idea, was it a competent response, or were they just humoring me*".I doubt they were making fun of you. What matters is that his suggestion is useless. Lawyers use ambiguous terms such as "*a family member*" mostly when the detail is irrelevant or they don't know enough about the matter they assess or litigate. They will look ridiculous if they limit themselves to "*family member*" in custody & divorce cases. But that is nothing you need to worry about. Instead, you need to work on improving the intelligibility of your statements.

Comment: The q is what to do if the issue is not intel, you understand me & read me well. Sometimes its normal in convo to repeat what somebody else says to help in understanding them, otherwise you're expecting perfection from who (theoreticaly in this case of the question that is being posed) is reasonably often going to to have the "expected behavior" of being tense/stressed given the matter at hand often being very serious & even traumatic (as talking as a child about your parents can lead to immediate & long-term legal action which can not be readily controlled by any means friendly law or words).

Answer (score -3):

(1) The answer my Free Legal Aid Clinic student lawyer gave was that I could or should say: ***"A member of my family"***. Otherwise phrased "A family member".

(2) Alternatively, I've thought to use special spelling (but not for speaking verbally, it does not work) **"Parent(s)"**, deliberately not specifying if singular or plural seems to avoid direct (legal and otherwise) implication, which to some degree helps prevent guessing.

<sup>*Sensitivity-Warning: I hesitate to give their "A member of my family." variation as an option, because if you're hyperliterate you might notice the abbreviation spells **"A m o m f"** which has "mom" in it (that is partially why I asked the question for other options). I am worried that some might say that hints, gives away, or signals that the Mom not the Dad is the issue, in some communities where that superspelling matters too and may be noticed/valued itself as a response (some people professionally/cryptologically evaluate for initials/acronyms too), so I use with care.*</sup>

*<sup>General warning: From personal experience, first as a child, and then again later as an adult, the advice I got from legal counsel (and not just free legal aid, my parent(s) hired their own lawyers as well over many years several people) and also going to Maryland state representative with my parent(s) in Annapolis, the brief answer is **"You're not addressed by the law specifically, it is not a standard issue, talking about your parents as a child is not well defined by current legal standards."* The main/primary issue I was alerted to was the general warning that what I said would determine which parent owned me (lawyers words were "They will own you until you are 18.") until I was 18, so "watch what you say" from an adult lawyer staring at a kid alone in a room for a rushy 15 minute session.*</sup>*